# How do I fix this strange effect that happens when I start animating items that are set to cloth in physics?

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

When I animate my mesh I'm building, the cloth parts start to look all funny.  I was wondering if this is normal or if there is a way to fix it?[image]

Comment: Are you using a solidify modifier? if so, move the cloth sim modifier above that.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! do you want to add that as the answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your Solidify modifier is above the Cloth modifier:

[image]

This means the cloth simulation will use that double layer of geometry, which can cause some instability and self-intersections.

In your case, the inside layer is poking through the outside layer and causing shading issues due to the fact that the normals of the new outside layer are facing the wrong way:

[image: normals]

The easiest way to solve this is to move the Solidify modifier below the Cloth one, so that the cloth simulation happens before the second layer of geometry is created:

[image: move mod]

---

However, if for some reason you need to take the solidified geometry into account for the cloth simulation, keep the Cloth modifier at the bottom and make sure *Self Collision* is enabled and uses a high enough quality to avoid instability:

[image: cloth self collision]